# How to browse a list<Class> In c++

Tags: c++, list, loops, class, iterator

I'm having a problem here and I thought I would find an easy answer on the Internet, but it's been 1 hour and I can't solve it. Seems so simple, but I can't find a way...

I've got 2 classes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class classB;

class classA{
private :
    string name;
    list<classB*> listClassB;

public:
    void getListClassB() const;
};

class classB{
private:
    string name;
    list<classA*> listClassA;

public:
    void getListClassA() const;
};
```

What I do on the `getListClassB()` method is:

```cpp
void classA::getListClassB() const {
    for(list<classB*>::iterator it = listClassB.begin(); it != listClassB.end; it++){
        //Stuff
    }
}
```

Visual Studio Code tells me that there is an error is on `listClassB` from `list<classB*>::iterator it = listClassB.begin()`

The complete error about that is:

```
there is no appropriate user-defined conversion of 
"std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::conditional_t<true, std::_List_simple_types<classB *>, std::_List_iter_types<classB *, size_t, ptrdiff_t, classB **, classB *const *, classB *&, classB *const &, std::_List_node<classB *, void *> *>>>>\" in \"std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::conditional_t<true, std::_List_simple_types<classB *>, std::_List_iter_types<classB *, size_t, ptrdiff_t, classB **, classB *const *, classB *&, classB *const &, std::_List_node<classB *, void *> *>>>>"
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, so thanks again for all your time, but this error makes me crazy.

I completed a bit the code to be more explicit about my work.

I don't go deeper because it's college work in France, and it's about UML classes, so it's class linked with others classes...

Comment: Try `(*it)->str`

Comment: Side note: `list`s of pointers are not all that useful unless you're storing polymorphic objects. `list` has fantastically forgiving [iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules-for-c-containers) so you don't have to worry about inserts and removals screwing things up so you don't get much in trade for the extra pointer chasing and possibly memory management woes if you're dynamically allocating the `Whatever`s.

Comment: `iterator it = myList.begin()` is correct, the error is in how you dereference. Trying to change how you initialize the iterator is just making it worse.

Comment: You should put together an actual [mcve] if you're still having trouble with this. In your example there's no `;` at the end of the class definition and no constructor that makes `Whatever wtvr("hey");` work. If I correct both of those issues *and* properly dereference the iterator it works fine for me. https://ideone.com/FelLN9

Comment: Your function is marked `const`, therefore you must use `const_iterator`, not `iterator`.  Otherwise you are breaking the language rules.  You are also missing parentheses on your call to `end()` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks dude it's finally working you're saving me !

Comment: You can also just do `auto it = listClassB.begin()` to avoid needing to write the name longhand.

Answer (score 5):

First, iterator is a pointer semantic object, so you have to dereference it to access the actual object. `it.str` makes no sense, since `std::list<>::iterator` has no `str` member (and even if it did, that would have nothing to do with `str` member of `Whatever` class.

Second, your list elements are pointers themselves, so this means you need a second indirection in order to access the `str` member:

```
std::cout << (*(*it)).str;
```

More appealing syntax would be:

```
std::cout << (*it)->str;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I did a double-take after your claim that `->` would magically follow a chain of pointers.  That was news to me! ;)

Comment: That's different.  My mistake was not noticing the list was storing pointers, since the title of the question was about `list<Class>`.  I think about 3 other people fell into the same trap! :)

Comment: Yeppers. <puts hand up.> Almost closed the question as a typo until I spotted that little complication.

Comment: Wait, why _doesn't_ a single `->` work? I thought that was the point of the `->` rules that allow you to do `std::unique_ptr<Foo> pFoo; pFoo->fooMember;`

Comment: @paddy `->` does chain dereferencing, but not in a way I used in the example. Looks like I needed a refresher there.

Comment: @NathanPierson But an iterator that references a pointer (`unique_ptr` or other wise) needs two dereferences to get at the object. One to deref the iterator and one to deref the pointer at the iterator.

Comment: Oh, the chain stops because `iterator::operator->` is returning a `Whatever**` not the pointed-to `Whatever*`.

Comment: Sounds like I need to go do some reading on chain dereferncing.  It's great how a trivial example from a learner opened up a deeper topic! XD

Comment: @NathanPierson in order for `->` to keep dereferencing it should return pointer-like object, not actual pointer - it stops the chain when it actually finds a pointer, and iterator's `operator->` returns a pointer.

Comment: @paddy yeah, chain dereference always seemed a bit counter-intuitive to me, and here was I, embarrassing myself :)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I haven't been clear, sorry :/
I edited my post

Answer (score 1):

The error message is difficult to read with all the template stuff in it, but it basically boils down to this:

```
there is no appropriate user-defined conversion of 
"std::_List_const_iterator<>" in "std::_List_iterator<>"
```

`getListClassB()` is marked as `const`, so its `this` pointer is typed as `const classA *`, thus the `listClassB` member is implicitly `const` when accessed via `this`.

When `list::begin()` is called on a `const list` object, it returns a `list::const_iterator`, which your loop is trying to assign to a `list::iterator`, which is not allowed, hence the error.  `list::iterator` allows the `list` data to be modified, whereas `list::const_iterator` does not.  Which is why a `const_iterator` cannot be assigned to an `iterator`.

That being said, your `for` loop has another typo in it.  You need to change `listClassB.end` to `listClassB.end()` instead (notice the extra parenthesis), ie you need to *call* `end()` and compare its *return value* to `it`, not compare *`end` itself* to `it`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void classA::getListClassB() const {
    for(list<classB*>::const_iterator it = listClassB.begin(); it != listClassB.end(); ++it){
        //Stuff
    }
}
```

Note, however, that the `const_iterator`/`iterator` mismatch could have been avoided if you had used `auto` instead to let the compiler *deduce* the appropriate type for `it`, eg:

```cpp
void classA::getListClassB() const {
    for(auto it = listClassB.begin(); it != listClassB.end(); ++it){
        //Stuff
    }
}
```

But, a safer way to avoid both mistakes would be to use a [`range-for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop instead, eg:

```cpp
void classA::getListClassB() const {
    for(classB *ptr : listClassB){
        //Stuff
    }
}
```